# BibTeX: New entry for dictionary

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

The publisher of my PhD wants me to cite dictionaries in my bibliography as follows :

> DCECH = Corominal, Joan/Pascual, José Antonio, *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e histpánico*, 6 vol., Madrid, Gredos, 1980-1991.

As a reference in the text, it should only show the abbreviation:

> DCECH

I work with a modified version of `ksfh_nat` style that you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqgv85zxe7vavdo/Bianca.bst?dl=0).

I guess I will have to add a new entry type for dictionaries, but I'm not sure how. The style would be exactly the same as for a book entry, with the only difference that the author has to be preceded by `abbreviation =`, which should also be the part to be cited.

A simplified version of my code is:

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Cf. \cite{DCECH}\\

\bibliographystyle{Bianca}
\bibliography{bibliographie}

\end{document}
```

And the bibliography entry could look like this:

```
@Book{DCECH,
abbreviation (?? category not yet existing) = {DCECH},
author       = {Joan Corominas and José Pascual},
title        = {Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico},
year         = {1980-1991},
publisher    = {Gredos},
address      = {6 vol., Madrid},
}
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you set `ngerman` as a document class option but not state it as a language option when loading the `babel` package?

Comment: Does the publisher have some styles and example documents for you to look at?

Comment: I asked a few times but they say they don't have a bibtex bibliography style or an example to share....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows. First, change the bib entry to

```
@Book{DCECH,
abbreviation = {DCECH}, 
author       = {Joan Corominas and José Antonio Pascual},
title        = {Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico ({DCECH}), 6~vol.},
year         = {1980--1991},
publisher    = {Gredos},
address      = {Madrid},
}
```

(Aside: Is `abbreviation` a field name that's recognized by the Bibliography style you employ? I don't recognize it as a standard BibTeX field.)

Second, insert the following instruction in the preamble (after loading the `natbib` package):

```
\defcitealias{DCECH}{DCECH}
```

Third, use `\citetalias{DCECH}` instead of the usual `\citet{DCECH}` in the body of the document generate citation call-outs that say "DCECH" rather than "Corominas/Pascual (1980-1991)".

Comment: No, "abbreviation" is not recognized yet, but I would need this field as an option for the Book style. This way, if it is a dictionary, it would contain data and would appear correctly, but if it's a normal book, it would still appear correctly as a normal book entry.

Comment: @BiancaMertens - To my knowledge, most bibliography styles don't really do much with the `key` field *unless" the `author` field is missing -- which isn't the case here.

Comment: Could I define this in a way that the abbreviation would be cited for every @book entry containing an abbreviation? I have something like 50 dictionaries to cite and this would make a very long list of \defciteetalis{}{}....

Comment: @BiancaMertens - I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently proficient in BibTeX's programming language to be able to address your question.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to my .bst file :

```
abbreviation
```

as a new entry type with following code :

```
`FUNCTION {format.book.abbreviation}
{ abbreviation
 "abbreviation" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  {
  }
 if$
}
```

and below F`UNCTION{book}`, before `author empty$`, I added following code :

`abbreviation empty$
      'skip$
    {  ""
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate       format.book.abbreviation
       output.nonnull.nostate
       " = "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block`

Combined with the suggestion from Mico to use \defcitealias{DCECH}{DCECH}, I new get exactly the output I need :

> DCECH = Corominal, Joan/Pascual, José Antonio, Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e histpánico, 6 vol., Madrid, Gredos, 1980-1991.

Now, the only problem left is that I have about 50 dictionaries in my bibliography and using `\defcitetalias{}{}` will create a very long list of definitions. Is there any way to simplify this or to create a command that will will cite the entry `abbreviation` instead of `author.year` ?